# Error in search function of binary search tree

Tags: c++

```
struct node *search(struct node *root, int x)
{
    if(root->key == x || root == NULL)
    {
        return root;
    }   
    if(x < root->key)
    {
        return search(root->left, x);
    }
    else
    {
        return search(root->right, x);
    }
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault when I search for an element not in the binary search tree.. What's wrong?

Comment: FYI: in C++, a `struct` (and `class`) definition makes the new type usable without an additional `typedef` and without the repetition of the `struct` (unlike C, which requires one of those two).

Answer (score 2):

Switch `root->key == x` and `root == NULL` to take advantage of short-circuiting in the `||` operator. You want to check that it is *not* null, and *only then* try to get properties from it.

Right now, what happens when you get to a `search` on a node that has no children? You either get `search(root->left, x);` or `search(root->right, x);`, both of which are equivalent to `search(NULL, x);`.

At that point, the first `if` statement becomes `if (NULL->key == x || NULL == NULL)`. `NULL->key` is a dereference on the null pointer, which causes a seg-fault.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It worked.. Can you elabporate your comment.. I didnt understand it properly. I got that we make use of short-circuiting property of or gate here.. But even if we dont use it, the code shudnt give seg fault right?

Comment: @AnuragBharadwaj Edited my answer. This should be more clear now.